# Why this Auxiliary verb at the end with conjunction?

Tags: conjunction, auxiliary-verb

I was wondering why helping verb “hat” is at the end here:

“Ich weiß, dass Kolumbus Amerika entdeckt hat.”

Isn’t it supposed to be

“Ich weiß, dass Kolumbus hat Amerika entdeckt” ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In German word order, the conjugated verb takes the second position in *main clauses*, but the last position in *subordinate clauses*. The part starting with "dass" **is** a subordinate clause.